# how to create a websocket client in mule

Tags: websocket, mule, mulesoft, mule-connector

I'm trying to create a websocket client in mule which connect to external server websocket. Also I want to send the headers and body to external websocket at the time of connection request. How to achieve this in mule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to send a WebSockets request and set headers is explained in the [Mule WebSockets connector documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/websockets-connector/1.0/websockets-connector-config-topics). To send information you can use the [send operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/websockets-connector/1.0/websockets-connector-messaging-operations).

Example

```
<websocket:config name="wsClient">
    <websocket:connection>
       <websocket:client-settings host="localhost" port="${listenerPort}" basePath="/ws">
           <websocket:default-headers>
                <websocket:header key="myFirstDefaultHeader" value="defaultHeader1" />
                <websocket:header key="mySecondDefaultHeader" value="defaultHeader2" />
            </websocket:default-headers>
            <websocket:default-query-params>
                <websocket:query-param key="myFirstDefaultQueryParam" value="query1" />
                <websocket:query-param key="mySecondDefaultQueryParam" value="query2" />
            </websocket:default-query-params>
       </websocket:client-settings>
    </websocket:connection>
</websocket:config>

<flow="connectToWebSocketFlow">
    <websocket:open-outbound-socket
      path="/chat"
      socketId="myCustomWebSocketID-123"
      config-ref="wsClient" />
    </websocket:open-outbound-socket>

    <logger info="INFO" message="Opened connection to external service!"/>

     <websocket:send socketId="myCustomWebSocketID-123" config-ref="wsClient">
        <websocket:content>'Hello world!'</websocket:content>
     </websocket:send>
</flow>
```

Comment: tnx for the reply. How to pass the body here. Actually my websocket server expect the sessionId in body during connection request time. If I don't pass this in body it throws 400 bad request error. I've tried this through postman. But how to do the same in mule here ?

Comment: It is all there is the documentation. Have you tried to follow the documentation and had some issue? You are expected to do that in Stackoverflow.com. Anyway I have updated my answer to include sending information. I'm not sure what is the sessionId that you mentioned but you can put it in the `<websocket:content>` as needed.